# Removing duplicates from a String in Java

Tags: java, string

I am trying to iterate through a string in order to remove the duplicates characters.

For example the String `aabbccdef` should become `abcdef`
and the String `abcdabcd` should become `abcd`

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = new String("abbc");
        String output = new String();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < output.length(); j++) {
                if (input.charAt(i) != output.charAt(j)) {
                    output = output + input.charAt(i);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(output);

    }

}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you just want to 'collapse' repeating characters, or remove duplicates entirely. That is, should "abba" result in "aba" or "ab"?

Comment: I don't think code will work as given.. flow never enters second loop :)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Convert the string to an array of char, and store it in a `LinkedHashSet`.  That will preserve your ordering, and remove duplicates.  Something like:

```
String string = "aabbccdefatafaz";

char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
Set<Character> charSet = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
for (char c : chars) {
    charSet.add(c);
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Character character : charSet) {
    sb.append(character);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: I guess I can't really avoid StringBuilder or an array list...oh well, thanks

Comment: @Rico: You can also do this manually (like creating an array of the right length, then putting all non-duplicates in it, then creating a string of this), but it is simply more work this way, and a StringBuilder is really made to construct Strings.

Comment: This will also remove the second 'f', which may or may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: Using `new StringBuilder(charSet.size())` will optimize this slightly to avoid resizing the `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 23):

Using **Stream** makes it easy.

```
noDuplicates = Arrays.asList(myString.split(""))
                     .stream()
                     .distinct()
                     .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

> Here is some more documentation about Stream and all you can do with
>   it :
>   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html
>
> The 'description' part is very instructive about the benefits of Streams.

Comment: can simplify with `Arrays.stream`

Answer (score 8):

Try this simple solution:

```
public String removeDuplicates(String input){
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if(!result.contains(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)))) {
            result += String.valueOf(input.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but each time `+=` gets run, the entire string is destroyed and re-copied resulting in unnecessary inefficiency.  Also testing for the length() of the string on every iteration of the loop introduces inefficiency.  The length of the loop doesn't change so you don't have to check it on every character.

Answer (score 6):

I would use the help of [LinkedHashSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html). Removes dups (as we are using a Set, maintains the order as we are using linked list impl). This is kind of a dirty solution. there might be even a better way.

```
String s="aabbccdef";
Set<Character> set=new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
for(char c:s.toCharArray())
{
    set.add(Character.valueOf(c));
}
```

Comment: Its not returning a String though.

Answer (score 2):

Create a StringWriter. Run through the original string using charAt(i) in a for loop. Maintain a variable of char type keeping the last charAt value. If you iterate and the charAt value equals what is stored in that variable, don't add to the StringWriter. Finally, use the StringWriter.toString() method and get a string, and do what you need with it.

Comment: I tried somethinig like that, but not StringWriter.toString(). The first loop would iterate through the input string and if that character did not exist in the result string then append it...but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class RemoveRepeated4rmString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "harikrishna";
        String s2 = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            Boolean found = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < s2.length(); j++) {
                if (s.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(j)) {
                    found = true;
                    break; //don't need to iterate further
                }
            }
            if (found == false) {
                s2 = s2.concat(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an improvement to the [answer by Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4989150/5221149).

It uses `HashSet` instead of the slightly more costly `LinkedHashSet`, and reuses the `chars` buffer for the result, eliminating the need for a `StringBuilder`.

```
String string = "aabbccdefatafaz";

char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
Set<Character> present = new HashSet<>();
int len = 0;
for (char c : chars)
    if (present.add(c))
        chars[len++] = c;

System.out.println(new String(chars, 0, len));   // abcdeftz
```

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 has a new `String.chars()` method which returns a stream of characters in the String. You can use stream operations to filter out the duplicate characters like so:

```
String out = in.chars()
            .mapToObj(c -> Character.valueOf((char) c)) // bit messy as chars() returns an IntStream, not a CharStream (which doesn't exist)
            .distinct()
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String input = "AAAB";

    String output = "";
    for (int index = 0; index < input.length(); index++) {
        if (input.charAt(index % input.length()) != input
                .charAt((index + 1) % input.length())) {

            output += input.charAt(index);

        }
    }
    System.out.println(output);
```

but you cant use it if the input has the same elements, or if its empty!

Comment: This will not work on the examples you asked about in [Remove duplicate in a string without using arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13866036/851811)

Answer (score 1):

Code to remove the duplicate characters in a string without using any additional buffer. NOTE: One or two additional variables are fine. An extra array is not:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
    public static char[] removeDupes(char[] arr){
        if (arr == null || arr.length < 2)
            return arr;
        int len = arr.length;
        int tail = 1;
        for(int x = 1; x < len; x++){
            int y;
            for(y = 0; y < tail; y++){
                if (arr[x] == arr[y]) break;
            }
            if (y == tail){
                arr[tail] = arr[x];
                tail++;
            }
        }
        return Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, tail);
    }

    public static char[] bigArr(int len){
        char[] arr = new char[len];
        Random r = new Random();
        String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*()-=_+[]{}|;:',.<>/?`~";

        for(int x = 0; x < len; x++){
            arr[x] = alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length()));
        }

        return arr;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){

        String result = new String(removeDupes(new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a'}));
        assert "abcd".equals(result) : "abcda should return abcd but it returns: " + result;

        result = new String(removeDupes(new char[]{'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'}));
        assert "a".equals(result) : "aaaa should return a but it returns: " + result;

        result = new String(removeDupes(new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'a'}));
        assert "abc".equals(result) : "abca should return abc but it returns: " + result;

        result = new String(removeDupes(new char[]{'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'}));
        assert "ab".equals(result) : "aabb should return ab but it returns: " + result;

        result = new String(removeDupes(new char[]{'a'}));
        assert "a".equals(result) : "a should return a but it returns: " + result;

        result = new String(removeDupes(new char[]{'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'}));
        assert "ab".equals(result) : "abba should return ab but it returns: " + result;


        char[] arr = bigArr(5000000);
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("2: " + new String(removeDupes(arr)));
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long duration = (endTime - startTime);
        System.out.println("Program took: " + duration + " nanoseconds");
        System.out.println("Program took: " + duration/1000000000 + " seconds");

    }
}
```

**How to read and talk about the above code:**

1. The method called removeDupes takes an array of primitive char called arr.
2. arr is returned as an array of primitive characters "by value".  The arr passed in is garbage collected at the end of Main's member method removeDupes.
3. The runtime complexity of this algorithm is O(n) or more specifically O(n+(small constant)) the constant being the unique characters in the entire array of primitive chars.
4. The copyOfRange does not increase runtime complexity significantly since it only copies a small constant number of items.  The char array called arr is not stepped all the way through.
5. If you pass null into removeDupes, the method returns null.
6. If you pass an empty array of primitive chars or an array containing one value, that unmodified array is returned.
7. Method removeDupes goes about as fast as physically possible, fully utilizing the L1 and L2 cache, so [Branch redirects are kept to a minimum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902).
8. A 2015 standard issue unburdened computer should be able to complete this method with an primitive char array containing 500 million characters between 15 and 25 seconds.

**Explain how this code works:**

The first part of the array passed in is used as the repository for the unique characters that are ultimately returned.  At the beginning of the function the answer is: "the characters between 0 and 1" as between 0 and tail.

We define the variable y outside of the loop because we want to find the first location where the array index that we are looking at has been duplicated in our repository.  When a duplicate is found, it breaks out and quits, the y==tail returns false and the repository is not contributed to.

when the index x that we are peeking at is not represented in our repository, then we pull that one and add it to the end of our repository at index tail and increment tail.

At the end, we return the array between the points 0 and tail, which should be smaller or equal to in length to the original array.

**Talking points exercise for coder interviews:**

Will the program behave differently if you change the y++ to ++y?  Why or why not.

Does the array copy at the end represent another 'N' pass through the entire array making runtime complexity O(n*n) instead of O(n) ?  Why or why not.

Can you replace the double equals comparing primitive characters with a .equals?  Why or why not?

Can this method be changed in order to do the replacements "by reference" instead of as it is now, "by value"?  Why or why not?

Can you increase the efficiency of this algorithm by sorting the repository of unique values at the beginning of 'arr'?  Under which circumstances would it be more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static void main(String a[]){
      String name="Madan";
      System.out.println(name);
      StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(name);
      for(int i=0;i<name.length();i++){
          for(int j=i+1;j<name.length();j++){
             if(name.charAt(i)==name.charAt(j)){
              sb.deleteCharAt(j);

             }
          }
      }
     System.out.println("After deletion :"+sb+"");

    }
```

Comment: Good to give some code, but it should come with some explanation to point the changes and why it is the solution of the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class dublicate {
    public static void main(String... a) {
        System.out.print("Enter the String");
        Scanner Sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String st=Sc.nextLine();
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        boolean [] bc=new boolean[256];
        for(int i=0;i<st.length();i++)
        {
            int index=st.charAt(i);
            if(bc[index]==false)
            {
                sb.append(st.charAt(i));
                bc[index]=true;
            }

        }
        System.out.print(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be greatly improved if it included an explanation of how and why this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. (Thanks @Toby Speight for this message)

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like everyone is trying way too hard to accomplish this task. All we are concerned about is that it copies 1 copy of each letter if it repeats. Then because we are only concerned if those characters repeat one after the other the nested loops become arbitrary as you can just simply compare position n to position n + 1. Then because this only copies things down when they're different, to solve for the last character you can either append white space to the end of the original string, or just get it to copy the last character of the string to your result.

String removeDuplicate(String s){

```
    String result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if (i + 1 < s.length() && s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(i+1)){
            result = result + s.charAt(i);
        }
        if (i + 1 == s.length()){
            result = result + s.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    return result;

}
```

Comment: I just realized his second example shows that it does remove duplicates even if they don't follow one another. So this solution is incorrect for what he/she is trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str1[] ="Hi helloo helloo  oooo this".split(" "); 

Set<String> charSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
for (String c: str1) 
{
       charSet.add(c); 
}
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
for (String character : charSet) 
{
       sb.append(character); 
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think working this way would be more easy,,, 
Just pass a string to this function and the job is done :) .

```
private static void removeduplicate(String name)
{   char[] arr = name.toCharArray();
    StringBuffer modified =new StringBuffer();
    for(char a:arr)
    {
        if(!modified.contains(Character.toString(a)))
        {
            modified=modified.append(Character.toString(a)) ;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(modified);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
public class RemoveDuplicatesFromStingsMethod1UsingLoops {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = new String("aaabbbcccddd");
        String output = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            if (!output.contains(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)))) {
                output += String.valueOf(input.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

**output:** abcd

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can create a new String that has duplicates removed. Why aren't you using StringBuilder (or StringBuffer, presumably)?

You can run through the string and store the unique characters in a char[] array, keeping track of how many unique characters you've seen. Then you can create a new String using the `String(char[], int, int)` constructor.

Also, the problem is a little ambiguous—does “duplicates” mean adjacent repetitions? (In other words, what should happen with `abcab`?)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void alpha(char[] finalname)
{
    if (finalname == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    if (finalname.length <2)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    char empty = '\000';
    for (int i=0; i<finalname.length-1; i++)
    {
        if (finalname[i] == finalname[i+1])
        {
            finalname[i] = empty;
        }
    }
    
    String alphaname = String.valueOf(finalname);
    alphaname = alphaname.replace("\000", "");
    System.out.println(alphaname);
    
        
}
```

Comment: This code makes two mistakes, first: it only replaces consecutive duplicates. It fails to compress `abcabc` to `abc` because inside your loop you are only testing the similarity of adjacent indices in the array.  second: you are passing a char[] by reference, and in order to change the array by reference is to destroy it and re-create it, forcing its lifetime to only exist in this particular method.  You'll have to return the variable, which makes a clone of the entire thing, one of which needs to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Oldschool way (as we wrote such a tasks in Apple ][ Basic, adapted to Java):

```
int i,j;
StringBuffer str=new StringBuffer();
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter string: ");
str.append(in.nextLine());

for (i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++){
    for (j=i+1;j<str.length();j++){
        if (str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(j))
            str.deleteCharAt(j);
    }
}
System.out.println("Removed non-unique symbols: " + str);
```

Comment: This answer is right, but it has a runtime complexity of `O(n * n * n )`.  Each time you call str.length, you are stepping the entire array.  Since an algorithm can be designed to do this in O(n) runtime complexity without using additional memory, this answer will get you in trouble if I see you put this sort of thing in production. This is the generic easy-to-understand answer given by programmers who write very VERY slow running code.  It's a good exercise in understanding runtime complexity.

Comment: O(n2) bad complexity

Answer (score 0):

Here is another logic I'd like to share. You start comparing from midway of the string length and go backward.

Test with:
input = "azxxzy";
output = "ay";

```
String removeMidway(String input){
        cnt = cnt+1;
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(input);
        int midlen = str.length()/2;
        for(int i=midlen-1;i>0;i--){

            for(int j=midlen;j<str.length()-1;j++){     
                if(str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(j)){
                    str.delete(i, j+1);
                    midlen = str.length()/2;
                    System.out.println("i="+i+",j="+j+ ",len="+ str.length() + ",midlen=" + midlen+ ", after deleted = " + str);
                }
            }
        }       
        return str.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void remove_duplicate (char* str, int len) {
    unsigned int index = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (c < len) {
        /* this is just example more check can be added for
           capital letter, space and special chars */

        int pos = str[c] - 'a';
        if ((index & (1<<pos)) == 0) {
            str[i++] = str[c];
            index |= (1<<pos);
        }
        c++;
    }
    str[i] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, in case a string is an ASCII string, is to maintain an array of 256 boolean elements to denote ASCII character appearance in a string. If a character appeared for the first time, we keep it and append to the result. Otherwise just skip it.

```
public String removeDuplicates(String input) {
    boolean[] chars = new boolean[256];
    StringBuilder resultStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Character c : input.toCharArray()) {
        if (!chars[c]) {
            resultStringBuilder.append(c);
            chars[c] = true;
        }
    }
    return resultStringBuilder.toString();
}
```

This approach will also work with Unicode string. You just need to increase `chars` size.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using JDK7:

```
public static String removeDuplicateChars(final String str){

    if (str == null || str.isEmpty()){
        return str;
    }

    final char[] chArray = str.toCharArray();
    final Set<Character> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for (char c : chArray) {
        set.add(c);
    }

    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Character character : set) {
        sb.append(character);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str = "eamparuthik@gmail.com";
    char[] c = str.toCharArray();
    String op = "";

    for(int i=0; i<=c.length-1; i++){
        if(!op.contains(c[i] + ""))
        op = op + c[i];
    }
    System.out.println(op);
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String removeDuplicateChar(String str){
         char charArray[] = str.toCharArray();
         StringBuilder stringBuilder= new StringBuilder();
         for(int i=0;i<charArray.length;i++){
             int index = stringBuilder.toString().indexOf(charArray[i]);
             if(index <= -1){
                 stringBuilder.append(charArray[i]);
             }
         }
         return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class RemoveDuplicacy
{
        public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("Enter any word : ");
            String s = br.readLine();
            int l = s.length();
            char ch;
            String ans=" ";

            for(int i=0; i<l; i++)
            {
                ch = s.charAt(i);
                if(ch!=' ')
                    ans = ans + ch;
                s = s.replace(ch,' '); //Replacing all occurrence of the current character by a space
            }

           System.out.println("Word after removing duplicate characters : " + ans);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i,j;
    StringBuffer str=new StringBuffer();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter string: ");

    str.append(in.nextLine());

    for (i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++)
    {
        for (j=1;j<str.length();j++)
        {
            if (str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(j))
                str.deleteCharAt(j);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Removed String: " + str);
}
```

Comment: Please, do not only give code, explain what was wrong and how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is improvement on solution suggested by @Dave. Here, I am implementing in single loop only.

> Let's **reuse the return** of **set.add(T item)** method and add it simultaneously in StringBuffer if add is successfull

This is just O(n). No need to make a loop again.

```
String string = "aabbccdefatafaz";

char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Set<Character> charSet = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
for (char c : chars) {
    if(charSet.add(c) ){
        sb.append(c);
    }

}
System.out.println(sb.toString()); // abcdeftz
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to iterate through the given string and put each unique character into another string(in this case, a variable **result** ) if this string doesn't contain that particular character.Finally return **result** string as output.

Below is working and tested code snippet for removing duplicate characters from the given string which has O(n) time complexity .

```
private static String removeDuplicate(String s) {
      String result="";
      for (int i=0 ;i<s.length();i++) {
          char ch = s.charAt(i);
          if (!result.contains(""+ch)) {
              result+=""+ch;
          }
      }
      return result;
  }
```

If the input is **madam** then output will be **mad**.
If the input is **anagram** then output will be **angrm**

Hope this helps.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the simplicity of the code- I have taken hardcore input, one can take input by using Scanner class also

```
    public class KillDuplicateCharInString {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str= "aaaabccdde ";
        char arr[]= str.toCharArray();
        int n = arr.length;
        String finalStr="";
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            if(i==n-1){
                finalStr+=arr[i];
                break;
            }
            if(arr[i]==arr[i+1]) {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                finalStr+=arr[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(finalStr);



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = sc.next();
    String str = "";
    char c;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        c = s.charAt(i);
        str = str + c;
        s = s.replace(c, ' ');
        if(i == s.length() - 1)
        {
           System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\s", ""));   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Give some explanation about your solution and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.st.removeduplicate;
 public class RemoveDuplicate {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1="shushil",str2="";      
    for(int i=0; i<=str1.length()-1;i++) {
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++) {
            if(str1.charAt(i)==str1.charAt(j)) 
                count++;
            if(count >1)
                break;
        }
        if(count==1) 
            str2=str2+str1.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println(str2);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

```
public void RemoveDuplicates() {
    String s = "Hello World!";
    int l = s.length();
    char ch;
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        ch = s.charAt(i);
        if (ch != ' ') {
            result = result + ch;
        }
        // Replacing space in all occurrence of the current character
        s = s.replace(ch, ' ');
    }
    System.out.println("After removing duplicate characters : " + result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

've an array to know whether a character has already been recorded or not; if not, add that to the string buffer. Please note that I have made it case sensitive; with the int array, you can always make it('ve not done that in this code) to return the number of occurrences too.

```
private static String removeDuplicates(String s) {

    int [] occurrences = new int[52];
    Arrays.fill(occurrences,0);

    StringBuffer deDupS = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if(s.charAt(i) >= 97) {
            if(occurrences[s.charAt(i) - 97] == 0) {
                deDupS.append(s.charAt(i));
                occurrences[s.charAt(i) - 97]++;
            }
        } else if(s.charAt(i) >= 65) {
            if(occurrences[s.charAt(i) - 65 + 26] == 0) {
                deDupS.append(s.charAt(i));
                occurrences[s.charAt(i) - 65 + 26]++;
            }
        }
    }

    return deDupS.toString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder builderWord = new StringBuilder(word);
 for(int index=0; index < builderWord.length(); index++) {
   for(int reverseIndex=builderWord.length()-1; reverseIndex > index;reverseIndex--) {
     if (builderWord.charAt(reverseIndex) == builderWord.charAt(index)) {
       builderWord.deleteCharAt(reverseIndex);
     }
   }
}
return builderWord.toString();
```

Comment: Please explain your code as well - don't just post a plain code block with no context

Answer (score 0):

```
public String removeDuplicates(String dupCharsString){
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(dupCharsString);
    int step = 0;
    while(step <= buffer.length()){
        for( int i = step + 1; i < buffer.length(); i++ ){
            if( buffer.charAt(i) == buffer.charAt(step) ){
                buffer.setCharAt(i, ' ');
            }
        }
        step++;
    }
    return buffer.toString().replaceAll("\\s","");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Sol {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] str = "bananas".toCharArray();
        LinkedHashMap<Character,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();

        for(Character c : str){
            if(map.containsKey(c))
                map.put(c, map.get(c)+1);
            else
                map.put(c, 1);
        }

        for(Entry<Character,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
            s.append(entry.getKey());
        }

        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
String s = "WelcomeToJava";
String result = "";
List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < s.length(); k++) {
        if (String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)).equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(s.charAt(k)))) {
            if (!al.contains(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)))) {
                al.add(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
                result = result + String.valueOf(s.charAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("Result--" + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.stream(input.split("")).distinct().collect(joining());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String input = "abbcccaabbddeessacccbbddefgaabbccddeeffggadscsda";
    String output ="";

    for (int i= 0; i<input.length();i++) {
        if (!output.contains(input.substring(i, i+1))) 
            output = output+ input.substring(i, i+1);

    }


        System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: Very inefficient, since in the worst case, you are traversing the whole output on every iteration.  Check out other answers using sets which are arguably more efficient. Since there are already so many answers, it's only useful to post your own if you also provide an explanation on what makes it good.

Answer (score 0):

```java
package StringPrograms;

public class RemoveDuplicateCharacters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean flag;
        String str = "Stackoverflowtest";
        String a = "";
        int dlen = a.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            flag = false;
            for (int j = 0; j <dlen; j++)
                
                 if (str.charAt(i) == a.charAt(j)) {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            if (flag == false) {
                a = a + str.charAt(i);
                dlen = dlen + 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(a);

    }

}
```

Comment: Output : Stackoverflws

Answer (score 0):

```
String output = "";
    HashMap<Character,Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if (!map.containsKey(ch)){
            output += ch;
            map.put(ch,true);
        }
    }
    return output;
```

This is the simple approach using HashMap in Java in one pass .

Time Complexity : O(n)

Space Complexity : O(n)

Answer (score 0):

```
package JavaPracticePackage;

public class Replace_same_char {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value = "AABBCCDD";
        String FinalValue = "";
        for(int i=0; i<value.length();i++) {
            if(FinalValue.indexOf(value.charAt(i))==-1) {
                FinalValue=FinalValue+value.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(FinalValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HashSet class in java:

```
public static String removeDuplicates(String str) {
        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            set.add(String.valueOf(chars[i]));
        }
       return String.join("", set);
    }
```

Example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(removeDuplicates("aabbccdd")); // abcd
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this simple solution using Set collection concept:
String str = "aabbcdegg";

```
    Set<Character>removeduplicates = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    char strarray[]= str.toCharArray();
    for(char c:strarray)
    {
        removeduplicates.add(c);
    }


    Iterator<Character> itr = removeduplicates.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.print(itr.next());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class StringTest {

    public static String dupRemove(String str) {

        Set<Character> s1 = new HashSet<Character>();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

            Character c = str.charAt(i);

            if (!s1.contains(c)) {
                s1.add(c);
                sb.append(c);
            }


        }

        System.out.println(sb.toString());

        return sb.toString();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        dupRemove("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBB");
    }

}
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I ask you a couple of questions. Why are you posting two very similar answers to the same question? How is your approach different from previously posted answers?

Answer (score -1):

```
public class RemoveDuplicate {

    static String st="papuuu";
    static String st1="";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++) {
            String ff = String.valueOf(st.charAt(i));
            if (!st1.contains(ff)) {
                st1 = st1 + st.charAt(i);
            }
        }   
        System.out.println(st1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
  let str = 'abcdabddbbccedbd'; 
  let res = "";
  new Set([...str]).forEach((val) => {
      res += val
  })

  console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
package com.core.interview.client;

import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Set;

public class RemoveDuplicateFromString {

    public static String DupRemoveFromString(String str) {

        char[] c1 = str.toCharArray();

        Set < Character > charSet = new LinkedHashSet < Character > ();

        for (char c: c1) {

            charSet.add(c);
        }

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        for (Character c2: charSet) {

            sb.append(c2);
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter Your String: ");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );

        String str = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println(DupRemoveFromString(str));
    }
}
```