# Removing repeated characters, preserving order

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to write a code that takes in a `String` and removes repeating characters in that `String`.

```
String utenRepetisjon(String tekst) {

    String b;

    char[] tekstArray = tekst.toCharArray();
    char[] tilTekst = new char[tekstArray.length];

    for(int i=0; i<tekstArray.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<tekst.length(); j++) {
            if(tekstArray[i] != tekst.charAt(j)) {
                tilTekst[i] = tekstArray[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return b = new String(tilTekst);
}
```

E.g. If `tekst = "aababbabbac"`, it should return `"abc"`.
So far my code only return the same tekst that it's given..

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989091/removing-duplicates-from-a-string-in-java

Comment: How is your code supposed to work? tilTekst is created with the same length as tekst, which makes no sense in your problem because returned string is quite often smaller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the next:

```
String utenRepetisjon(String tekst) {
    String str = "";
    for(char ch : tekst.toCharArray()) {
        if (str.indexOf(ch) == -1) {
            str += ch;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Would be nicer with a `StringBuilder` or a character array. But it works.

Comment: +1 for an elegant solution.

Comment: Nice, short solution. But it might suffer from the infamous String-concatenation problem when tekst is very long. StringBuilder doesn't work as it does not have a indexOf(char).

Comment: Thank you! This one does the job :)

Comment: Suggestion: Use StringBuilder for concatenation and write a helper-method 'contains(StringBuilder, char)'.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the code.
Use a hashmap

```
 String tekst = "aababbabbac";
    char[] testArray = tekst.toCharArray();
    Hashtable<String, String> hash = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    for (char c : testArray) {
        if (!hash.containsKey("" + c)) {
            hash.put("" + c, "1");
        }
    }
    String dups = "";
    for (String key : hash.keySet()) {
        dups+=key;
    }
    System.out.println(dups);
```

Comment: That prints bac not abc. You need to maintain the order of the letters in the original word (not the downvoter).

Comment: Ya. I thought he wanted to just filter duplicates...And thanks for the negative !!

Comment: I'm not the downvoter btw.

Comment: Someone who agrees with my comment ?

Comment: Change to `java.util.LinkedHashSet` for maintains the order in which elements were inserted.

Comment: +1 for reading my mind...I was just gonna say that !