# How to remove duplicates of a string from another string in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

So I need to remove duplicates of a specific string from another string in Java, a few examples:

```
'test12312312312'       -> Remove duplicates of '123', output -> 'test12312'
'my sentence-!!!!!!!!!' -> Remove duplicates of '!!' , output -> 'my sentence-!!!'
'3rd ?!?!?!abd%3!?!?!??'-> Remove duplicates of '!?' , output -> '3rd ?!?!abd%3?'
```

Hopefully those examples make this clear. e.g. you pass a function any two strings, and it removes all duplicates of the first one from the second. For example it might look like:

```
String removeDuplicates(String checkString, String message) {
    //Return 'message' with duplicates of 'checkString' removed
}
```

I've seen various implementations of this for removing all instances of the string, or removing duplicates of a specific character - but none that keep the first occurance of a string. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty solving it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989091/removing-duplicates-from-a-string-in-java

Comment: Second example is wrong. If you remove *duplicate* `!!` values then `!! !! !! !! !` (spaces added for clarity) becomes `!! !`, i.e. the three duplicates of `!!` has been removed, leaving the first instance, so the result is `'my sentence-!!!'` (3 bangs, not 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation that gives you the output in the updated examples.

```
private static String removeDuplicates(String checkString, String message) {
    int idx = message.indexOf(checkString); // Find first occurrence of checkString
    if (idx == -1)
        return message; // No occurrence of checkString found
    idx += checkString.length(); // Skip first occurrence of checkString
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(message);
    while ((idx = buf.indexOf(checkString, idx)) != -1)
        buf.delete(idx, idx + checkString.length());
    return buf.toString();
}
```

It's not the most *optimal* way of doing it, but it is a fairly simple solution.

*Test*

```
System.out.println(removeDuplicates("123", "test12312312312"));
System.out.println(removeDuplicates("!!", "my sentence-!!!!!!!!!"));
System.out.println(removeDuplicates("!?", "3rd ?!?!?!abd%3!?!?!??"));
```

*Output*

```
test12312
my sentence-!!!
3rd ?!?!abd%3?
```

Answer (score 1):

With `String#replace`:

```
String needle = /* search string */;
String base = /* input string */;
int firstLoc = base.indexOf(needle);
if (firstLoc > 0) {
    int cutoff = firstLoc + needle.length();
    return base.substring(0, cutoff) + base.substring(cutoff).replace(needle, "");
}
return base;
```

Outside of that, you can iterate through the string, and if the first character of your search string matches the current character you are at, see if the remainder makes up the string in total. If it does, then just skip ahead. You're essentially just rebuilding the string:

```
//Precondition: needle not empty, vars not null, etc
StringBuilder back = new StringBuilder();
String needle = /* search string */;
String base = /* input string */;
boolean first = true;
for (int i = 0; i < base.length(); i++) {
    char c = base.charAt(i);
    if (c == needle.charAt(0)
          && base.substring(i, Math.min(base.length(), i + needle.length())).equals(needle)) {
        if (first) {
            first = false;
        } else {
            i += needle.length() - 1;
            continue;
        }
    }
    back.append(c);
}
return back.toString();
```

Comment: That removes *all* instances, not just the duplicates. First instance of `needle` has to remain in the result.

Comment: Whoops, you're correct. I missed that they wanted to keep the first. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
String removeDuplicates(String checkString, String message) {
    return checkString.replaceAll("("+message+")+", message);
}
```

this will leave a single `message` behind in a chain of `message`.
this only works if they are followed immediately by one another.

Comment: Why call `replace` twice? Why not 3 times, 4 times, ...?

Comment: You have to do it twice as replace continues replacing after reinserting the new string in the string to avoid infinite loops, leaving half of the instances of the duplicates, running it a second time leaves only one.

Comment: `removeDuplicates("ABABABABABABABABABAB", "AB")` returns `ABABAB`. That's not right. --- Also, you have parameters reversed. See comment in question code: *//Return 'message' with duplicates of 'checkString' removed*.

Comment: my bad, mistook the replace of java with the one in js.

Comment: See third example in question. Your updated code will fail terribly on it. And you still have the parameters reversed. *(wish I could down-vote again)*

Comment: What's fun about getting everything chewed in mummy's mouth? I will not reverse the parameters in your honor, as it is standard to put the object before the modifier.

Comment: That's ok. If you want to leave a useless (i.e. incorrect) answer, that's your prerogative. And I'm not talking about parameter order when I say *incorrect*.

Comment: You are dragging me down and beating me with experience, good job.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 ways:

1. Find first occurence of your substring. If there's no occurence, return input string. If there is such occurence, save everything up to that point (together with that occurence), remove all occurences further in input string.
2. Split input text on repeated string. Return result[0] + repeated + rest.join("")

Not sure which way will be faster.