# How can I convert "AaabBbbc" to "AabBc" in Java using regex?

Tags: java, regex

I tried this:

```
str.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");
```

But the output I got was Aa**b**B**b**c but **b** is already came before.

How can I remove the second occurrence of **b**.

---

***Update***
The aim is to remove all the duplicate alphabets after the first occurrence of that alphabet.

Also the uppercase and lowercase alphabets are to be treated differently.

Comment: What's the logic? You want to get `Aa`from `Aaa`, but you want `Bbb` to become just `B`.

Comment: To clarify/update your question use [edit] option.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to remove all characters that have already occurred earlier in the string? If so, this really isn't a task for regex.

Comment: `str.replace("AaabBbbc","AabBc")` meets the requirement you've stated. This is a lesson in stating your requirement adequately. None of us know what rule you actually want to apply.

Comment: can you tell us the X problem instead of Y(see [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: Why use a regex ? Maybe an ordered set would be enough (e.g. LinkedHashSet) ?

Comment: Is the answer to your actual problem already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34730085/7756856)?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: @KartikPatodi Could you add some demo cases? Some that should match, and some that shouldn't.

Comment: Test Cases ==>

Banana -> Ban ||
Semester -> Semstr ||
AaaaaaaaAaaaaa _-> Aa

Comment: What's the purpose? Would it be OK if the last instance is kept, instead of the first I.e. `Banana` -> `Bna`, `Semester` -> `Smster`.

Comment: @KartikPatodi What you just described is just removing [duplicated letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989091/removing-duplicates-from-a-string-in-java), which really shouldn't be attempted with regex.

Answer (score 1):

The best, although still weird, solution using regex that I could come up with so far is below.

If I can figure out a solution that doesn't require to reverse the string, I'll update this.

`RegexTest.java`

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class RegexTest {

    public static String removeDupeLetters(String input) {
        // Because look-behinds have to be fixed width, we have to use look-aheads instead.
        // As a result of that we'll have to reverse the string and start from the end. (And then reverse the result again)
        return reverseString(reverseString(input).replaceAll("([A-Za-z])(?=.*\\1)", ""));
    }

    // helper function for reversing a String
    public static String reverseString(String input) {
        return new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String[] inputs = {"AaabBbc", "Banana", "Semester", "AaaaaaaaAaaaaa"};
        for (String input : inputs) {
            System.out.println("Input:  " + input);
            System.out.println("Output: " + removeDupeLetters(input));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

`javac RegexTest.java && java RegexTest`

```
Input:  AaabBbc
Output: AabBc

Input:  Banana
Output: Ban

Input:  Semester
Output: Semstr

Input:  AaaaaaaaAaaaaa
Output: Aa
```

Note: As pointed out in the comments, it probably makes more sense to use a solution that does not involve regex at all, see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989091/removing-duplicates-from-a-string-in-java)... was fun anyway though :D