# Narrow down common elements between strings

Tags: java

```
public class numerodetel {**strong text**    
static void commun(String tel1, String tel2){
    for(int i=0;i<tel1.length();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<tel2.length();j++){
            if(tel1.charAt(i)==tel2.charAt(j))
                System.out.printf(" %c,", tel1.charAt(i));

        }

    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
        String telUDM = "5143436111", telJean = "4501897654";

        commun(telUDM, telJean);
    }
}
```

The code works and I am able to find the common numbers between the two phone numbers. Is there an easy way, though, to make it so that once a common number is detected between the two, it doesn't reappear again? In this case it would be 5, 1, 4, 6.

Answer (score 1):

First you can remove the repeated numbers from the string using something like what is suggested here:

[Removing duplicates from a String in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989091/removing-duplicates-from-a-string-in-java)

Then, you can use break statement to leave the inner loop every time a match is found:

```
static void commun(String tel1, String tel2) {
    for(int i=0;i<tel1.length();i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<tel2.length();j++) {
            if(tel1.charAt(i)==tel2.charAt(j)) {
                System.out.printf(" %c,", tel1.charAt(i));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It still repeats numbers

Comment: Are you sure? Does it keep going after "5" from "telUDM" and "45" from "4501897654"?

Comment: how would you do that

Comment: when i only put break it still repeats

Comment: but when i copy paste what you wrote it just stops at 5 and doesn't give anything else

Comment: @CharlesAllo isn't that what you expected? To stop after you find a match?

Comment: yeah but I wanna find other matches so that it gives out: 5, 1, 4, 6

Comment: Ok. Now I got what you want. I guess the easiest way would be to remove the repeated numbers from the the first string and then to use this method.

Comment: Is there a method to systematically do that? Since these are phone numbers

Comment: No, but you can write your own method if it will be useful for you multiple times.

Comment: Yeah the original question I'm asking how would one go about exactly that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class numerodetel {**strong text**    
static void commun(String tel1, String tel2){
    dstr="";
    for(int i=0;i<tel1.length();i++){
        if (dstr.indexOf(tel1.charAt(i)) >= 0)
            continue;
        for(int j=0;j<tel2.length();j++){
            if (tel1.charAt(i)==tel2.charAt(j)) {
                dstr += tel1.charAt(i);
                System.out.printf(" %c,", tel1.charAt(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
        String telUDM = "5143436111", telJean = "4501897654";

        commun(telUDM, telJean);
    }
}
```

Simply updated your own codes.
It's to maintain a dumplicates string `dstr` here, common chars will add into it.
When a letter already in it, then will skip the comparing by `continue`.
`indexOf` will return the position of the letter in the string, or `-1` if not in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want duplicates, use `Set`.

This will also perform better *O(n+m)*, instead of the *O(n*m)* of your code.

```
static void commun(String tel1, String tel2) {
    Set<Integer> chars1 = tel1.chars().boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Set<Integer> chars2 = tel2.chars().boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
    chars1.retainAll(chars2);
    for (int ch : chars1)
        System.out.printf(" %c,", (char) ch);
}
```

*Test*

```
commun("5143436111", "4501897654");
```

*Output*

```
 1, 4, 5, 6,
```